# List item like gradient buttons

Tags: html, css

I know it might sound quite basic but I'm slightly newbie to HTML. I would like to have list of items that are looking like gradient buttons. I know how to make a list with unordered list element but have trouble with styling side.

```
<ul>
<li>List item #1</li>
<li>List item #2</li>
<li>List item #3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `like gradient buttons`

Comment: Plz read FAQ's of the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to insert the following style block into your head tag.

```
<style>
.the-list {
    padding:0;
}
.the-list li {
    list-style:none;
    margin-top:8px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-radius:5px;
    padding:5px;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    background: linear-gradient(white, #eee);
}
</style>
```

Here's the fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/fL5tj/

Comment: Ayhan, I tried your code yet. It gives me a quite similar look to what I was trying to have it like. I think I just got to modify the colours only. It works mate thanks!

Comment: Happy to see it helped. Have a good day :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
li {
 background: linear-gradient(to top, #F0FAF8, #306AA8);
 border-radius: 5px;
 list-style: none;
 width: 100px;
 padding-left:28px;
 margin:2px 0 0 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XN4QE/

Answer (score -2):

If you mention gradient style means give the rough prototype to suggest the idea on the same